# inserting ViewController In between the stack of self.navigationController.viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have three viewcontollers in my navigation controller. Now what i want to do just insert a view controller in between the array of self.navigationController.viewControllers.

As I checked the **property viewControllers is not a readonly property** So i think we can set it also.
thats why I used the below code to insert my ViewController in between the stack.
But unfortunately it doesn't modify the stack of **self.navigationController.viewControllers.**

**So how can I insert and modify the stack. Also be sure that I don't want to pushViewcontroller.**

```
    CXSTransactionSelectionViewController *trxSelectionVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CXSTransactionSelectionViewController"];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [viewControllers insertObject:trxSelectionVc atIndex:viewControllers.count-2 ];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

Comment: @gran33 because we can't insert any object in NSArray and the self.navigationController.viewControllers returns the NSArray. thats why i first convert it to MutableArray then insert a object into it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using this my problem is resolved

```
CXSTransactionSelectionViewController *trxSelectionVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CXSTransactionSelectionViewController"];
[self.navigationController.viewControllers insertObject:trxSelectionVc atIndex:1 ];
NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

Comment: How on the earth did you insert a view controller to the `viewControllers` when that is merely a `NSArray` not a `NSMutableArray` and hence doesn't support `insertObject` selector by its own?

Comment: @AyanSengupta It could be done at the time answer was posted here is swift version  nav?.viewControllers.insert(<#T##newElement: UIViewController##UIViewController#>, at: <#T##Int#>)

Comment: @amar it works in swift because `NSArray` gets bridged to `Array<UIViewController>` (ie, a value type). calling `navigationController.viewControllers.insert()` implicitly calls `-[UINavigationController setViewControllers:]`, which you need to do manually in ObjC

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
NSArray * oldViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSArray * newViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[oldViewControllers objectAtIndex:0], newVC, [oldViewControllers objectAtIndex:1],nil];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers];
```

Comment: thanks for the support @gran33 but it's the same that I tried and it's not working .

Comment: Give some more details please.