# Push View from Presented View Controller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

**In Short :**
How can I PushViewController from Presented ViewController ?

**In Brief :**

I have `MainViewController`, In which I have one button on click of button, I am presenting a view called `LoginViewController`.

On this page (`LoginViewController`), I again have `button`, on click of that, I try to push my view controller(called `HomeViewController`) it doesn't pushes.

Here is my code snippet,

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender {
    LoginViewController *vc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)buttonActionMethodOnLoginView:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"viewControllers %@",APPDELEGATE.nav.viewControllers);
     //LoginViewController is not in this array
     HomeViewController *obj = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

But it did not works for me. Also, I printed `a stack of view controllers` before `pushed`, but it doesn't have `LoginViewController`. So, without adding `LoginViewController` into `a stack of view controllers`, How can I `pushed` to `HomeViewController` from `LoginViewController` ?

**When I getBack from `HomeViewController`, then `LoginViewController` should get opened..**

Is it possible using doing this single `NavigationController`?

**Note:-** Here, I have just taken an example using Login, Home and Main ViewController. But I want that into Other Screens.

Comment: Does `LoginViewController` implement `UINavigationViewController`? You can try to push `HomeViewController` with `self presentViewController` like LoginViewController.

Comment: Yes, I can `present` that `HomeViewController`. But, I want to `push` that `HomeViewController` from `LoginViewController`..

Comment: Your LoginViewController must have its NavigationController to push from LoginView Controller.

Comment: @technerd : Yes, But how can I done that ?

Comment: @MeetDoshi, have you checked my answer? Did you get some help?

Comment: @MeetDoshi The recent update in your question changes it totally and none of the answers is matching the "new" question.

Comment: I know that.. But I want that.. And Thanks for answering to solving my this issue..  Please help me according this.. And my recent update on this question works into accepted answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `Push` from your firstView (`MainViewController`), but you can use animation same as `PresentView` and `DismissView`. Use following code for this :-

**For Push** (on `MainViewController`)

```
LoginViewController *VC = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3f;
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                            forKey:kCATransition];
[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC] pushViewController:VC animated:NO];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:NO];
```

**For Pop** (on `LoginViewController`)

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3f;
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                            forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Using this code, you can get animation same as `Present-Dismiss ViewControllers`. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29210265/3908884) for more details.

And after that, you can use your code for `Pushing` `LoginViewController` to `HomeViewController`

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)

Answer (score 29):

hi when you are Presenting you Login view controller Just present a navigationController like:

```
LoginVC *loginVCObj =[[LoginVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVCObj];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now your PresentedViewController is An navigtioncontroller 
now you can simply push to your Home VC

```
  HomeViewController *obj = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: Using this code, I can able to `pushed` view controller. But `LoginVC` doesn't `dismissed`. So when I dismiss `LoginVC`, then it get back to `HomeViewController`. And when I `pop` this, It get back to `MainViewController`. So this doesn't solved my issue.

Comment: Let me explain acc. to my code. when u r on mainVC and Presenting 'UINavigationController' nav. now you are on different NavigationController Not on previous one if you wanna push to HomeVC from LoginVC. your mainVC not be in this Navigation.

Comment: Okay. But how can done this with one `NavigationController`?

Comment: @Shubhambairagi What did you put into the completion block? OMG

Answer (score 12):

`LoginViewController` should not be pushed to navigation controller stack. Let me describe below "why".

Our `MainViewController` should be on the stack - you always want to go back there.

```
// AppDelegate.m (only if you don't use storyboards, if you do - you don't need to copy this part of code)
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // create the window
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // set view controllers
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MainViewController alloc] init]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
}
```

On specific action show `LoginViewController`. You don't want the user to be able to tap `back` and go to `MainViewController`. Later, you won't want user to go back to `LoginViewController`. Because of this, you need to present it as modal:

```
// inside `MainViewController.m`
- (IBAction)myCoolActionToShowLogin:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:[[LoginViewController alloc] init] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now we can see `LoginViewController`. When user completes the login, dismiss it and present `HomeViewController`:

```
// inside `LoginViewController.m`
- (IBAction)myAwesomeActionToShowHome:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow rootViewController];
    [navigationController pushViewController:[[HomeViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

NOTES:

As you may notice, `myAwesomeActionToShowHome:` expects you have navigation controller as your `rootViewController`. This is working, but should be nicer - you should check if that navigation is in fact navigation controller instead of casting it. Or you may create a delegate or block to push new one. This is the fastest, easiest working solution, which should be improved later.

You **really** should read: [Apple Developer -> "View Controller Programming" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html), as these are the **core fundamentals** you should know to develop & design UX correctly.

Here is the working [demo sample](https://github.com/natalia-osa/SOFPushPopDemo).

Comment: As you didn't mention, I assumed you don't use Storyboards. This affect only AppDelegate. If you use Storyboards, you have the entry in AppDelegate "completed" by Storyboard and you don't have to use that code. Anyway, two methods left are correct for both Storyboard and Code solutions.

Comment: This doesn't work me.. Using this, when I trying to push a view from presented view, at that time a view controller pushed but never showed, when I dismissed my presented view, at that time my pushed view showed. So, My issue was, when I push a view controller from presented view, at that time I want to show that pushed view controller without dismissing my presented view..

Comment: @MeetDoshi I've added one line inside the code of `myAwesomeActionToShowHome`, where the current controller is being dismissed.

Comment: Ok thanks.. here you dismissed that view when we push.. But now when I get back from HomeViewController, then I want to open my presented view (LoginViewController), then how can I do this..?

Comment: @MeetDoshi I've created a working demo for you :) Please check out the link: https://github.com/natalia-osa/SOFPushPopDemo

Comment: Usually there shouldn't be a possibility to go back to the LoginViewController. In most cases, when user logs in, he never wants to go back to that screen. Common practice is to add navigationBarButtonItem to sign out. But there is no need to display LoginViewController once user logged in. Probably your user experience will suffer upon this decision.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and Demo.. Yes I know.. Here, I have just take one example for LoginViewController. I want that into other screens. Your demo works same.. But I wants that, When I getBack from CViewController, then BViewController should get opened..

Comment: @MeetDoshi If you want to get back to that controller, it shouldn't be presented via `presentViewController:animated:` but via `self.navigationController pushNavigationController:`. The navigation controller stack will handle going back and forward. `present..` should be used only when you want to show it and not "save in history". You seem to have some holes in knowledge about how to work with `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController` and managing view controllers. Please read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html.

Comment: Ok thanks.. and please update your answer with SOFPushPopDemo code link.. Thats really nice demo.

Comment: @MeetDoshi Glad I was able to help and thanks for accepting. Provided the link to the demo in the answer ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can't push from a presented view controller. I suggest, you should maintain your navigation hierarchy.

For that, from your MainViewController, you should present LoginViewController and you should pass navigation controller for the MainViewController.

```
- (IBAction)openLogin:(id)sender {
    LoginViewController *loginVC = (LoginViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    [loginVC setReferencedNavigation:self.navigationController];
    [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then inside LoginViewController, you should push to HomeViewController like this,

> LoginViewController.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {
    UINavigationController *refNavigationController;
}
- (void) setReferencedNavigation:(UINavigationController *)refNavCon;
```

> LoginViewController.m

```
- (void) setReferencedNavigation:(UINavigationController *)refNavCon {
    refNavigationController = refNavCon;
}

- (IBAction)openHome:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        UIViewController *homeVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
        [refNavigationController pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

By doing this, it will be look like, you're pushing from LoginViewController but in reality you're pushing from MainViewController.

You can customize this approach to maintain animation and UI for this flow.

[image]

Comment: Its working for storyboard.. But what about xib?? I want to implement this into xib project.

Comment: Why? What's the issue with XIBs? You only need to change the way you'll create object of your view controller.

Comment: Yes I tried that.. But manually I can not able add my viewcontroller in to Navigation Controller stack..

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22981748/1603234), [this](http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20782023/1603234). These links show you how to create navigation controller and attached a view controller programmatically. Let me know if you still need more help.

Comment: I already checked that. And I tried this.. 
`NSArray *stack = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], myViewController, nil];` 
`[self.navigationController setViewControllers:stack animated:NO];` using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26844821/3908884) .

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this. It seems to be improper. Instead, your MainViewController should be inside `UINavigationController`. Thus, you don't need to reset anything while presenting `LoginViewController`. E.g. `LoginViewController *controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

Comment: Because I can not able to used `setReferencedNavigation` method at my end. I don't know why I can not able to used that.. Thats why I tried that..

Answer (score 8):

1) present a `navigation controller with its`root view controller` set as view controller .

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender 
{
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)buttonActionMethodOnLoginView:(id)sender
{
    HomeViewController *obj = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `LoginViewController` has no navigation controller. Then you give it one.

#### MainViewController.m

Create a `UINavigationController`, put `LoginViewController` in to the stack and present the `UINavigationController`.

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender {
    LoginViewController *vc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController = nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    nav.viewControllers = @[vc];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

#### LoginViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonActionMethodOnLoginView:(id)sender{
    HomeViewController *obj = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

#### Dismiss

Call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` in your `MainViewController`.

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3.0

Present your view controller as a new rootViewController

```
let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController"))
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Now push your view controller from presented view controller

```
self.show(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController"), sender: self)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a UINavigationController instance

`[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[LoginViewController alloc] init]]`

Present that navigationController and then push whatever VC you want to.

Answer (score 4):

**MainViewController.m**

```
 - (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender {

     LoginViewController *vc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

     UINavigationController *loginNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc]; 

     [self presentViewController:loginNav animated:YES completion:nil];  

 }
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)buttonActionMethodOnLoginView:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"viewControllers %@",APPDELEGATE.nav.viewControllers);
     //LoginViewController is not in this array
     HomeViewController *obj = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't works for me.. Why you are presenting viewController two times ??

Comment: yes, it is typing mistake. now you can try. it will work

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple code for present view controller and push view controller.

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender {
        LoginViewController *objLogicVC = [LoginViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navPresent = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objLogicVC];
        [self presentViewController:navPresent animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)buttonActionMethodOnLoginView:(id)sender{
        HomeViewController *objHomeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objHomeVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You didn't get my point. Please Read my Question once again.. My main issue was, *When I getBack from HomeViewController, then LoginViewController should get opened..*

Answer (score 3):

simply put this code in **objective c** on **button** **action**

```
UIViewController *yourViewControllerName = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerName "];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:yourViewControllerName  animated:YES];
```