# Can't pop viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, catransition

I'm using this code to show a UIViewController:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.f;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:NO];
```

and the viewController is displayed correctly. Then I'm using this code to prepare an animation (Used to animate the pop):

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.f;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

However, neither of these lines will pop it:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

**What could be the issue?** Logging the navigation stack displays both the correct `UIViewControllers`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

Comment: with out animation try once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik same result without animation

Comment: ya , ok check once your view controllers are added in Navigation stack or not....

Comment: Try to add animation to the view controllers view that's being pushed/popped on `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:`. That should work.

Comment: Not really answering your question per se, but if you are trying to implement  custom view controller transitions, take a look at the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol, as well as this article on objc.io: https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/.

Comment: Try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34591394/3908884

Comment: @MeetDoshi hmm. It appears the controls on the `UIViewController resets to their default state when I call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is embarrassing.

I was running the push call in the `viewDidAppear:animated:`, and I had forgotten to implement a check if we had already pushed. So when I popped the new `UIViewController`, the `viewDidAppear:animated` re-pushed the new VC again. I also set the it to `animate:NO` and removed the custom transition, causing the pop and re-push to happen basically instantaneously.

I discovered this by putting a breakpoint at the pop message, and noticed the simulator displayed the root `UIViewController` for a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2):

This is clear,

if you don't **push** yourViewcontroller, you can't pop yourViewController

if bellow line is missing in your code

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:NO];
```

none of the both bellow will execute

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Strange, I'm using this line

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:NO];`

To push my viewController

Comment: In you 2nd option of code fragment you didi not use '[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:NO];'. this is the reason you can't pop

Comment: Oh, that code isn't when pushing - I added it prior to calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` to animate the pop. Don't know if this is right though - but I removed it just now

Comment: It appears the controls on the `UIViewController resets to their default state when I call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: what do you mean by reset to default state.

Comment: For instance, I've got a `UISlider` that snaps back to its default value when I try to pop. It's also worth mentioning that this slider is inside a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I think I've made a quite obvious mistake here. Let me see

Answer (score 0):

set your navigationItems left / right / title  to nil before

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

I saw some thing similar today where the view did not update after pop